Is it correct method that using polar coordinate to calculate multi variable limit?
Determine whether limit exists or dosen't exist, if limit exists then find that value.
$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow  (0,0)}{\arctan(\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2})}$

solution 1 
WLOG suppose $ |x| \geq |y| $

$\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2} \geq \frac{|x|+|y|}{(|x|+|y|)^2} \geq \frac{1}{|x|+|y|} \geq \frac{1}{2|x|} $
 Since $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{1}{2|x|}} = \inf $
$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0,0)}{\arctan(\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2})} = \frac{\pi}{2} $

solution 2
Let $ x = r \cos { \theta }, y = r \sin {\theta} $
 $ \frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2} =  \frac{r|\sin{\theta} | + r | \cos {\theta } | }{r^2} \geq \frac{2 \sqrt{| \sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}|}}{r}  $
since $ \lim_{r \rightarrow 0+}{\frac{2 \sqrt{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}}{r}} = \inf $ $
\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0,0)}{\arctan(\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2})} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$

I think solution 1 is correct but solution 2 is worng beacuse that way can consider only line for arbitrary constant $\theta$. But my friend tell me that $\theta$ is a function of r, so polar coordinate can consider all way. What is correct?

Then, how does polar coordinate method consider all way (line, $y=x^2$... etc)?

Write down the definition  of $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\infty$. No curves are involved.

I realized both are correct in this problem. But I can't understand $\theta$ is neither constant nor function of r. How can I explain $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}{\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}}$?

To prove that a limit does not exist, you can indeed find two curves (no matter if it is in polar or cartesian coordinates) along which the limit is not the same. But this is a distinct situation from that of your post.

Then, are you saying polar coordinate method can be used only for particular situation?

No matter if you use polar or cartesian coordinates. What I am saying is that to prove a limit exists you don't consider curves, whereas to prove a limit does not exist, you (often) do.

Don't I need to consider curves to prove that a limit exists? I'm confused.. I know that 'If limit is constant for any curves, then limit exists, if not, dosen't exist', so I have to consider all curves to prove limit exists. In this case, If for some curve $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}{\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2 + y^2}} = 1$, then limit of posted problem dosen't exist, so considering curve is important. What did I get wrong?

Considering curves is useful for disproving the existence of a limit. In the posted problem the limit exists, and your "if for some curve lim=1" does not happen. "If limit is constant for any curves, then limit exists" is true but useless as a tool for proving this existence, because considering all curves is untractable.

For $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$, limit is 0 for $y = x$ but limit is 1/2 for $y^2 = x$. I'm afraid being some function which makes limit not $\inf$, other constant. I can't understand why I don't need to consider all curves to prove existence. I know that squeezing thm or epsilon-delta can consider all curves indirectly (because these methods are not related with kind of curve.) So I think these two methods are only method for proving existence because It's difficult to consider all curves directly. But polar coordinate method looks considering particular curve.. so I asked that

"Polar method" does not "consider particular curve". Your friend is wrong in telling you that $\theta$ is a function of $r$. Again: write down the definition of $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\infty$, or equivalently $\lim_{r\to0}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\infty$.

I got it. Thanks :)

In the second method, keep in mind that
$\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta} = 0$ whenever $\theta$ is an integer multiple of $\pi/2$. Therefore
$$ 
\lim_{r \to 0+}{\frac{2 \sqrt{\lvert\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\rvert}}{r}} \neq \infty . 
$$
The limit does not exist, because every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ contains both points where $\frac{2 \sqrt{\lvert\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\rvert}}{r}$ is arbitrarily large and points where $\frac{2 \sqrt{\lvert\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\rvert}}{r}=0$.
But the original limit exists. You just need to choose a better way to find it in polar coordinates.
A good strategy would be to observe that
$$
\frac{r\lvert\sin{\theta}\rvert + r \lvert\cos {\theta } \rvert }{r^2}
= \frac{\lvert\sin{\theta}\rvert + \lvert\cos {\theta } \rvert }{r}
$$
and to find a single positive number that is a lower bound of $\lvert\sin{\theta}\rvert + \lvert\cos {\theta } \rvert$ for every $\theta$.
As for what to say about $\theta$,
in order to find a limit at $(0,0)$ you must consider neighborhoods of $(0,0)$.
Usually we consider neighborhoods that are punctured disks. Within a punctured disk, at each value of $r$, $\theta$ takes all values. Therefore you should not treat $\theta$ either as a constant or as a function of $r$.

Are you saying that 'for r=0.01 where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$, for r=0.001 where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$,... therefore considering is like punctured disk, so It can be regarded as considering all curves'?

That may be a reasonably intuitive way to look at it.

I think I understood almost.. But I need to prove this way. Can you give me some hint?

Which way is "this way"? What is your definition of a limit of a function of two variables?

I expressed polar coordinate method as 'this way'. I got it, it's enough to replace all x, y of definition with epsilon-delta to polar coordinate right? Because they are one-to-one corresponding. thanks :)

A nice thing about doing this in polar coordinates is that the formula of the punctured disk is much simpler: $0<r<\delta$ instead of $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$.
